# Authzforce problem installation unhealthy

Tags: authzforce

I have a problem with installation of Authzforce: "`Context [/authzforce-ce] startup failed due to previous errors`" . But, I don't get the error when I remove the volumes part in authzforce in the .yml file, but I don´t achieve to find the domains preload without volumes. Any solution? Thanks.
I have this .yml file:
authzforce:

```
image: fiware/authzforce-ce-server:release-8.0.1
hostname: authzforce
container_name: fiware-authzforce


networks:
  default:
    ipv4_address: 172.18.1.12
ports:
  - "8080:8080" # localhost:8080
volumes:
  - ./authzforce/domains:/opt/authzforce-ce-server/data/domains
healthcheck:
  test: curl --fail -s http://localhost:8080/authzforce-ce/version || exit 1
```

my start-up log is this:

```
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.167 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.35
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.280 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Nov 3 2018 17:39:20 UTC
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.296 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.35.0
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.305 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.308 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.15.0-109-generic
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.318 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.332 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.384 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-2~deb9u1-b13
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.385 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.396 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.401 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.410 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.414 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.436 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.439 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.484 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.501 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms1024m
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.508 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx2048m
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.515 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.533 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.543 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.564 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.603 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.616 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.621 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.641 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.648 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.18] using APR version [1.5.2].
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.664 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.675 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
13-Jul-2020 23:02:32.834 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017]
13-Jul-2020 23:02:36.801 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
13-Jul-2020 23:02:37.410 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
13-Jul-2020 23:02:38.252 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
13-Jul-2020 23:02:38.352 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
13-Jul-2020 23:02:38.384 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 25561 ms
13-Jul-2020 23:02:39.751 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
13-Jul-2020 23:02:39.792 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.35
13-Jul-2020 23:02:40.542 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor [/usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/authzforce-ce.xml]
13-Jul-2020 23:03:38.492 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
13-Jul-2020 23:03:38.955 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [350] milliseconds.
13-Jul-2020 23:03:39.074 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/authzforce-ce] startup failed due to previous errors
13-Jul-2020 23:03:39.906 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor [/usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/authzforce-ce.xml] has finished in [59,364] ms
13-Jul-2020 23:03:40.039 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager]
13-Jul-2020 23:03:42.682 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager] has finished in [2,643] ms
13-Jul-2020 23:03:42.724 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
13-Jul-2020 23:03:43.353 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [630] ms
13-Jul-2020 23:03:43.393 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager]
13-Jul-2020 23:03:44.971 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [1,551] ms
13-Jul-2020 23:03:44.979 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs]
13-Jul-2020 23:03:46.032 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs] has finished in [1,053] ms
13-Jul-2020 23:03:46.075 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples]
13-Jul-2020 23:03:53.996 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples] has finished in [7,921] ms
13-Jul-2020 23:03:54.154 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
13-Jul-2020 23:03:54.440 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
13-Jul-2020 23:03:54.517 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 76084 ms
```

Comment: Please try the latest version 8.1.0.

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: There should be more error logs in either /var/log/tomcat8/authzforce-ce/error.log or one of /var/log/tomcat8/localhost.XXX.log . Could you check these?

Comment: 2020-07-17 11:05:20,822|ERROR|localhost-startStop-1|org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader:351|Context initialization failed|
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.NamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/core]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXB

Comment: Could you post the full stacktrace? The interesting part is at the end but it seems to be cut here in the middle of the class name (JAXB???) in your comment.

Comment: I put it in the question because the comments comments have a word limit

Comment: with docker, I can only see logs exposed in the question.

Comment: To see the other logs in the docker, you'll have to go inside: $ docker exec -it fiware-authzforce bash

Comment: In the docker container, logs are not in /var/log/tomcat8 but /usr/local/tomcat/logs, there you should see the localhost.XXX.log and authzforce-ce/error.log

Comment: Anyway I assume this issue resolved on authzforce github: https://github.com/authzforce/server/issues/54

Answer (score 0):

The root cause and resolution of the issue was handled on [AuthzForce Github issues](https://github.com/authzforce/server/issues/54).